# json-ld alias not parsing

Tags: python, json, schema.org, json-ld

I am trying to learn json-ld and I am having some problems with aliases.

When I use the JSON-ld playground with the following context and document:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "url": "@id",
    "a": "@type",
    "name": "http://schema.org/name",
    "schema": "http://schema.org/"
  },
  "url": "http://example.com/about#gregg",
  "a": "schema:Person",
  "name": "Gregg Kellogg"
}
```

this compacts properly to:

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "id": "http://example.com/about#gregg",
  "type": "Person",
  "name": "Gregg Kellogg"
}
```

as can be seen here: https://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-compacted&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22url%22%3A%22%40id%22%2C%22a%22%3A%22%40type%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fname%22%2C%22schema%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2F%22%7D%2C%22url%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fabout%23gregg%22%2C%22a%22%3A%22schema%3APerson%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Gregg%20Kellogg%22%7D&context=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2F%22%7D

Howevever when I use the Python pyld library with the following code:

```
from pyld import jsonld
import json

doc = {
    "url": "http://example.com/about#gregg",
    "a": "schema:Person",
    "name": "Gregg Kellogg"
}

context = {
    "url": "@id",
    "a": "@type",
    "name": "http://schema.org/name",
    "schema" : "http://schema.org/"
  }

compacted = jsonld.compact(doc, context)

print(json.dumps(compacted, indent=2))
```

only the context is printed without the document:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "url": "@id",
    "a": "@type",
    "name": "http://schema.org/name",
    "schema": "http://schema.org/"
  }
}
```

Could anyone explain why the aliases are not being applied when I use the pyld library and what I am doing wrong?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two examples are not the same.  The problem with the Python example is that the input doc does not have a context.  The processor first expands the data and will result in unknown terms that are dropped.  You can see the problem if you print out the expanded data:

```py
expanded = jsonld.expand(doc)
print(json.dumps(expanded, indent=2))
```

```json
[]
```

If you add in the context, then expand, you will see the correct data:

```py
from pyld import jsonld
import json

context = {
    "url": "@id",
    "a": "@type",
    "name": "http://schema.org/name",
    "schema" : "http://schema.org/"
}

doc = {
    "@context": context,
    "url": "http://example.com/about#gregg",
    "a": "schema:Person",
    "name": "Gregg Kellogg"
}

expanded = jsonld.expand(doc)
print(json.dumps(expanded, indent=2))
```

```json
[
  {
    "@type": [
      "http://schema.org/Person"
    ],
    "http://schema.org/name": [
      {
        "@value": "Gregg Kellogg"
      }
    ],
    "@id": "http://example.com/about#gregg"
  }
]
```

To match your compaction playground example, you would want to add in the context as above and compact with the schema.org context:

```py
...
compacted = jsonld.compact(doc, {"@context": "http://schema.org/"})
# or use the shortcut:
# compacted = jsonld.compact(doc, "http://schema.org/")
print(json.dumps(compacted, indent=2))
```

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "id": "http://example.com/about#gregg",
  "type": "Person",
  "name": "Gregg Kellogg"
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation, much obliged! :)